# Building wheel for neural-renderer (setup.py) ... error

Tags: python, c

When I reproduced the code of this paper “https://github.com/iPERDance/iPERCore”, I ran python setup.py develop and reported ERROR: Failed building wheel for neural-renderer[enter image description here][1]

And my ubuntu environment is :
CUDA V10.1.243
gcc 7.5.0
Ubuntu 18.04.5
pytorch 1.7.0+cu101

Comment: You probably don't have the dependencies to build the project.  You may wish to consult the project page and find this [installation](https://github.com/iPERDance/iPERCore/blob/main/docs/install.md) document that will guide you.

Comment: I did it according to the installation document

Comment: You might want to file this directly as an issue on the project, with the full traceback of the issue as that is the most direct way to get them to know of the trouble you are having.